# Is it a common pattern in Python to have instance variables assigned in a constructor start with an underscore?

Tags: python, patterns-and-practices

I recently started using [UtilSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), a Vim plugin allowing for a certain level of automation while coding by using template-like code snippets for common code fragments (class and function definitions, for example).

When using a popular [snippet pack](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) with Python, I noticed that snippets used when writing a class use a pattern I've never seen before in `__init__` when using more arguments than just `self`:

```
class MyClass(object):

    """Docstring for MyClass. """

    def __init__(self, user, password):
        """TODO: to be defined.

        :user: TODO
        :password: TODO

        """
        self._user = user  # this is the pattern I'm unfamiliar with
        self._password = password
```

Is it common (or good) practice to use underscore when assigning instance variables in a constructor for a class in Python, or is this likely just the snippet pack author's preference? I haven't seen this type of naming convention in any other Python code I've interacted with.

Comment: See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables): one leading underscore marks a field as private by convention, though it does not actually hide the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Leading Underscores

A leading underscore means "hands off" to the user, though an advanced user may expect to use it in certain circumstances, such as when subclassing your object.

## Usage demonstration with property decorator

We tend to use underscores when using a property, for example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        self._user = user
        self._password = password
    @property
    def user(self):
        return self._user
    # The rest are optional - leaving off has same behavior
    # but this demonstrates usage.
    @user.setter
    def user(self, value):
        """optional, raise a custom AttributeError message"""
        raise AttributeError('do not attempt to modify user member')
    @user.deleter
    def user(self):
        """optional, raise a custom AttributeError message"""
        raise AttributeError('do not attempt to modify user member')
```

So one using your code can create the object, 
but when attempting to modify the attribute
they get a warning telling them hands off, for which you ostensibly have a good reason:

```
>>> mc = MyClass('foo', 'bar')
>>> mc.user = 'huh?'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in user
AttributeError: do not attempt to modify user member
>>> del mc.user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in user
AttributeError: do not attempt to modify user member
```

Without our optional setter and deleter methods we get a more generic error message:

```
>>> mc.user = 'huh?'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> del mc.user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't delete attribute
```